# App Call Main Launcher launch from different icon/shortcuts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, application-state

Launch application from Desktop shortcut icon. Start Activity A by app launcher on activity a have button for move to Activity B and finish activity A. I pressed button and moved to Activity A to Activity B.

Now, I minimize app and again click on desktop short cut it show previous state of application with same instance (no new instance created) but if  I click from application drawer app icon its create new instance with launcher activity A. and If press back button and close app (Current new created instance) after it show previous instance with Activity B.

This issue with only shortcut created by Play store after installed new application.
Issue with desktop shortcut of play store and app drawer (if created new short cut of app, it treated same app drawer means it no create new instance)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="x.x.x" android:versionCode="17" package="com.pack1.client">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    <application android:label="@string/appName" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:name=".GlobalApplication" android:process=":authProcess">
        <activity android:label="@string/appName" android:name=".Login" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.pack1.client.LiveRequest">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>     
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectionChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>    
        <activity android:label="" android:name="com.pack1.client.Preferences" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:label="" android:name="com.pack1.client.UserInfo" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It means it works fine if you testing directly without downloading from playstore?

Comment: Yes! @PratikButani. it has only problem with short cut which created by play store.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare finish() on Activity A after going to Activity B. In this case, No old instances will remain from Activity A. Same goes when going from Activity B to Activity A.

Hope this one helps.

Comment: yes. I always finish Activity A when start Activity B.